# C# DataGridView show Tooltip text over every row on mouse hover

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tooltip, rows

I have a Winforms DataGridView to which I'm adding rows in the code. I need to add different Tooltip texts to each row in the grid and should appear when I mouse hover on respective row.

I have method something like this where I'm adding rows and wants to set the tool tips.

```
    private void AddConnections()
    {

      if(something is wrong)
      {
        // I need to set tooltip text here
      }

    dgvConnections.Rows.Add("val1","val2","val3");

    }
```

Kindly suggest some workarounds that I can set the tooltips for each row here.

Thanks!

Comment: [DataGridViewRow ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) don't have tooltips. But cells do. So you can set the same value to each cell.

Comment: @TaW is it possible to set tooltip to every cell of that same row while I'm adding data in that row?

Comment: Well you can once the row and all its cells __exist__, not before! The cell content is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I just created a custom method to set the tool-tip and passed it a respective row id like below.

```
private void SetToolTipText(DataGridViewRow row, String message)
{
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            cell.ToolTipText = message;
}

private void AddConnections()
{
            int rowId = dgvConnections.Rows.Add(" --  row contents --");
            SetToolTipText(dgvConnections.Rows[rowId], "some tool-tip text");
}
```